# How do I find all packages which are manually downgraded

Tags: apt, package-management, downgrade

Long time ago I downgraded some packages to make my wifi working more stable on toshiba notebook. Now I would like to get the system upgraded to ppa versions. I remember which packages they were anymore. Can I list all downgraded packages in synaptic or command line somehow ?

Comment: How did you downgrade the packages? Did you hold them? Did you update your system after that?

Answer (score 0):

If you held some packages from upgrading, you can list them by

```
apt-mark showhold
```